# How to send packets in a Minecraft Classic server written in Python

Tags: python, minecraft

I am designing a Minecraft Classic server written in Python, but I don't know how to send the packets properly. I know how to set up a socket, but the part I don't know is how to send them in the format needed by the protocol. I understand the protocol, just not how to implement it in Python. I don't really have code to post, just the heartbeat, and that's not relevant to my question. I have looked through the source of several servers, but I don't understand them.

Comment: use `struct.pack()`. [and note that there already exists several python minecraft servers. (what's on my wish list is a python minecraft client).]

Comment: @DanD. I was aware of the fact that others existed. I have looked through the source of several servers, but I don't understand them. Could you actually put the thing about `struct.pack()` into a full answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Dan D. mentioned you can use struct.pack to format your data as requested by the protocol. The documentation at http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html has a few examples.

Then you need to take a look at the packet structure at http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Classic_Server_Protocol#Packet_Protocol which describes in detail what your packets need to look like. According to the packet description you would need a struct.pack format string looking something like "Bbh" for the first 4 bytes.

```
struct.pack("Bbh", 0, 1, 7)
```

For a player identification packet with id 1 and protocol version 7. You will have to complete this with the rest of the packet 64 byte string + 1024 byte binary part, both with padding.

**EDIT:** Just remembered Python might not be native big endian so you might want to throw that into the format string as well.

```
struct.pack("!Bbh", 0, 1, 7)
```

You can find examples of packet formats and how to handle them by looking into the source of the myne2 server

https://bitbucket.org/andrewgodwin/myne2/src/236deac8cd2f/myne/core/constants.py

https://bitbucket.org/andrewgodwin/myne2/src/236deac8cd2f/myne/core/packeter.py

The [python module of the week page for struct](http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/struct/index.html) also has some very useful information.